# log4j multiple configuration files

Tags: log4j

I have couple of projects embedded in a web app as jars. Each project has a log4j.properties file. When the web app is deloyed, which configuration file gets used and how to override the configurations in log4j.xml in a jar file. The jars are not web projects. They are more like service layer code. What is the order in which the log4j.properties file is loaded in the below scenario

```
Web-project
   classes
      log4j.properties
   ProjectB.jar
      com
      log4j.properties
   ProjectC.jar
      com
      log4j.properties and so on.
```

Answer (score 5):

If your jars are separate web applications, each web application should use the one it first finds on the classpath (WEB-INF/classes).

You can pass a -Dlog4j.configuration=path_to_file setting to e.g. the tomcat startup to make sure that it uses the one you intend it to use. 
However, this would then to my understanding and knowledge be the one that tomcat will use for every webapp that is deployed.

Question here is how you deploy your apps. Either all web applications in one tomcat in which case you probably want each web application to use a different log4.properties (or log4j.xml) or in the case where you specify one to tomcat, it should use the one you specify.

What it boils down to as far as i know: Either the first one found on classpath (remember: each web-app has it's own classpath) or the one you specify via the -D setting.

Just found this reference which i think nicely summarizes the main concepts of logging in tomcat and webapps deployed in tomcat: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging

If you need even more control over the log4j logging, you can resort to coding the log4j configuration in java. However, this would mean that you have to modify the source code and add code into it, which relates to infrastructure and relates deployment details to your application (not so nice).

Comment: There is only one web app, but contains other jars that are not web applications but still have a log4j properties file

Comment: ok, understood. Is this a problem for your scenario? Do you see a need to override the log4j.properties that are contained in the jars? Can you influence the way the applications are developed and packaged?

Comment: in the example provided above. I don't think log4j.properties of ProjectA.jar or ProjectB.jar will get picked up. Instead of duplicating the contents of Log4j.properties in ProjectA.jar into the main log4j.properties, I was wondering if there is a way to load all 3 property files without duplicating.

Comment: Hm, now i understand your challenge. I think my answer states the actual behaviour of log4j, it's all about classpaths. In your case, I think the best solution is to actually provide one common configuration and (if possible) even remove the ones in the jars. Or, alternatively, make the jars load their respective config files programmatically (less nice I think).

Answer (score -1):

If you set additivity to false in common packages at ProjectA, ProjectB and WebProject your log will not duplicate.

log4j.additivity.[logged package] = false

For example:

log4j.properies -> Project A, Project B

log4j.additivity.org.spring.framework = false

All org.spring.framework log will come from WebProject ignoring ProjectA and ProjectB.

Comment: Does this work with separate configuration files, which is what this question is about?

Comment: It works only with spring jar loggers in my example but it can work with any pack logger.
The advantage is removing a logger in a "upper" config.